# Codeigniter return db result error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello Friends i have one problem with codeigniter and return db result using foreach i have this:

```
function get_test($id)
{
    $this -> db -> select('name, date, title, description');
    $this -> db -> from('table1');
    $this -> db -> join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.id');
    $this -> db -> where('table1.id', $id);

    $query = $this -> db -> get();
    return $query->row_array();   

      }
```

The Controller

```
function index()
{
   $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
    //SQL
    $data['results'] = $this->model1_model->get_test($data['id']);

    $this->load->view('base/header');
    $this->load->view('incidencia/index',$data);
}
```

The view

```
<?php foreach($results as $i): ?>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <p><b>Id incidencia:</b> <?php echo $i['id'];?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <p><b>Usuario:</b> <?php echo $i['name']; ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <p><b></b> <?php echo $i['title]; ?><p>
      <p><b></b> <?php echo $i['description']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But i have this error: Message: Illegal string offset 'name

Comment: This is because there is no index in the result set like 'name', check it by using print_r() on result set.

Comment: this means, there is no value in index `name`, and therefore it is not defined.

Comment: better check the condition there `if(isset($i['name'])) echo $i['name'];`

Comment: it´s the same friend i obtain the same error, but the name value exist because i get it from the bd, if i use this query it´s work but i need to use inner join  `return  $this->db->get_where('table1',array('id'=>$id))->row_array();`

Comment: I get to fix, the problem was the lowecase and uppercase these must be the same, if you get from the db with lowercase you must to write in lowercase in the view. Thanks

Comment: In stead of row_array() try result_array() in model.